Converting image data type from uint16 to uint8 using Python
I have a uint16 image, but when I want to convert this image to uint8 data type, I get bad results. I'm sharing my entry image and the result below. My image is a 3-channel RGB image.
original image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19ixbQhdhazV9mL_uSnTq-niZBmh5FO_h/view?usp=sharing

uint8 image

import rasterio

with rasterio.open(input_tiff) as src:
    profile = src.profile
    
    data = src.read()

    data_int8 = data.astype(np.uint8)
    
    profile.update(dtype=rasterio.uint8)

    with rasterio.open(output_tiff, 'w', **profile) as dst:
        dst.write(data_int8)


You can't just cast UINT16 to BYTE, if it's 16 bit then it's using all of those 16 bits, what you can see here is the result after truncation. You will need to cast to a memory block (array) and then scale the values into another memory block (divide by 255 usually works) then write the array to a new raster. You can do that in your code using numpy.

@Michael Stimson did you mean?
data_8bit = ((data - data.min()) / (data.max() - data.min()) * 255).astype(np.uint8)

I don't understand how, can you explain in more detail?

Your data corruption is caused by integer overflow.
Once a numpy integer goes outside the range of a datatype (0-255 for uint8), the value overflows and wraps around to 0 again.

For example:
np.uint16(255).astype(np.uint8) == 255
np.uint16(256).astype(np.uint8) == 0
np.uint16(258).astype(np.uint8) == 2
np.uint16(260).astype(np.uint8) == 4
np.uint16(511).astype(np.uint8) == 255
np.uint16(512).astype(np.uint8) == 0
np.uint16(514).astype(np.uint8) == 2
np.uint16(516).astype(np.uint8) == 4

A simple rescale will work, e.g.
data_8bit = ((data - data.min()) / (data.max() - data.min()) * 255).astype(np.uint8)

But you'll get a much nicer looking image if you rescale per band and even better with a per band percentile stretch similar to what most GIS software does, such as [2, 98] or [1, 99]. E.g.
import rasterio
import numpy as np

input_tiff = "test_uint16.tif"
output_tiff = "test_uint8.tif"

percentiles = [1, 99]

with rasterio.open(input_tiff) as src:
    profile = src.profile
    profile.update(dtype=rasterio.uint8)

    with rasterio.open(output_tiff, 'w', **profile) as dst:
        for i in range(src.count):
            band = i+1
            data = src.read(band, masked=True)

            # data.compressed() returns an array of non-masked pixel values
            pmin, pmax = np.percentile(data.compressed(), percentiles)

            # rescale 0-1
            data = (data - pmin) / (pmax - pmin)

            # Ensure data is >= pmin <= pmax
            data[data<0] = 0
            data[data>1] = 1

            # Make it 0-255 8bit unsigned.
            data_int8 = (data * 255).astype(np.uint8)

            dst.write(data_int8, band)


Shouldn't it be data_int8 = (data / 255).astype(np.uint8) to scale down 16 bit to 8 bit? Awesome comic panel to explain integer overflow!

@MichaelStimson No, because at that point data is floating point and scaled from 0-1 so it needs to be multiplied by 255 before casting to uint8.
